# $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{F}^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices

It is a fact of matrix multiplication that
$$\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & a & b \\&1&\\&&1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & a' & b'\\&1&\\&&1
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & a +a'&b+b' \\&1&\\&&1
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$

Therefore $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ contains a copy of the abelian group $\mathbb{F}^{n-1}$. Can we show that it does or does not contain a copy of $\mathbb{F}^n$, or any higher power?

**Edit:** Derek points out that, for even $n$, $\frac {n^2}{4}$ and for odd $n$, $\frac{n^2-1}{4}$ are possible. Can we show this the is highest value which is possible for all fields (while of course for specific fields higher may be possible)?

Comment: Assuming that blank matrix entries are $0$, your calculation is incorrect, and matrices of that form do not form a group. There should be a $b'+a$ in the top right entry of the product. To get a group isomorphic to ${\mathbb F}^{n-1}$, put your $a$ and $b$ along the top row of the matrix.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oops!

Answer (score 5):

There is a copy of $F^{(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)^2}$ in ${\rm GL}_n(F)$ for all $n$: put the nonzero off-diagonal entries in a square in the top right corner of the matrix.

I believe that, at least for finite fields, and possibly for ${\mathbb Q}$, this is the largest possible for $n>3$.

For some fields, such as ${\mathbb R}$, the additive groups of $F^n$ are isomorphic for all $n>0$.

Comment: Can you make precise which subgroup you mean in the first sentence?

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to draw a picture! I am talking about unimodular matrices in which the nonzero off-diagonal entries are in positions $(i,j)$ with $1 \le i \le m$ and $n-m+1 \le j \le n$, where $m = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$. (Sorry, I put $\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor$ before, which might have been the cause of confusion!)

Comment: Thank you. So for example for $n=4$ this is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & * & * \\ 0 & 1 & * & * \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. It's kind of surprising that the map $F^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor^2} \to \mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: I've just realized that for odd $n$ you can make it into an $\frac{n-1}{2} \times \frac{n+1}{2}$ rectangle and it's still abelian.

Comment: There is some related material on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29087/commutative-subalgebras-of-m-n .